# Qt sqlcipher on ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, build, sqlcipher

After hard work I did manage to build the sqlcipher using Qt on ubuntu.
The driver it is detected and loaded and works fine with not encrypted database.
The problem is when I try to execute some driver specific encryption sql query when it is not working. Let say the query it fails is "sqlcipher_export('dummyDB')".

Before of all have to encrypt an existing database so I do the next:

```
SUCCESS -> ATTACH DATABASE '/home/costy/test.db.tmp' AS dummy KEY 'foo'

FAILE -> SELECT sqlcipher_export('dummy')
```

I have this project working on Windows with out problems for more that 2 years and now did decided to make a Linux version also but this issue is holding me.

-

BTW there is another post asking about but I can not comment there 
[Build sqlcipher on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671741/build-sqlcipher-on-ubuntu)

The problem there is missing the OpenSSl library

```
cannot find -lcrypto -> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Other common error is missing SQLite library

```
cannot find -lsqlite3 -> sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify whether or not your driver is properly using SQLCipher by querying the current version of SQLCipher at runtime.  This can be accomplished by issuing the following command:

```
PRAGMA cipher_version;
```

It may be the case that `sqlcipher_export('…');` is failing because the Qt driver has not been properly built with SQLCipher and you may just be loading SQLite instead.

Comment: You are right that there is loaded a wrong driver. The "PRAGMA cipher_version;" returns NULL. Thanks...